# ASP.NET Core 6.0 : FluentValidation validators are registered but how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0, mediatr

Currently, I am working on a .NET Core 6.0 project that uses MediatR, Automapper, and FluentValidation.

I understand the FluentValidation validators are registered by using the "AddValidatorsFromAssembly" method like below

```
    public static void AddApplicationLayer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
    }
```

However, the project I am working on looks like this

```
    protected internal override void AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program));

        services.Scan(s => s
                        .FromAssembliesOf(this.AssemblyMarkerTypes)
                        .AddClasses(false)
                        .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Append)
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithTransientLifetime());

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        base.AddServices(services);
    }
```

It is not clear to me how FluentValidation validators are registered without calling **AddValidatorsFromAssembly**.

Additionally, it is not clear what the following code does.

```
        services.Scan(s => s
                        .FromAssembliesOf(this.AssemblyMarkerTypes)
                        .AddClasses(false)
                        .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Append)
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithTransientLifetime());
```

If the above scan, register all the DIs, why do we need a separate registrations for AddAutoMapper & AddMediatR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that project is using [`Scrutor`](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor). Based on provided code it will search in assemblies which contain some subset of types defined by `this.AssemblyMarkerTypes` for all non-abstract types classes ([including non-public](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/blob/b28d6ddf89c0b748cbc00c2a0b44dc4118e9cfa8/src/Scrutor/IImplementationTypeSelector.cs#L16)) and will register them as all implemented interfaces with transient lifetime.

Without access to the source code it is hard to argue what subset of assemblies is covered by `AssemblyMarkerTypes` but usually it should be all or almost all assemblies which are custom developed for the project, including the one containing validators.

> why do we need a separate registrations for `AddAutoMapper` & `AddMediatR`

Those methods also register some internal `AutoMapper` and `MediatR` stuff. There are 2 reasons why they would not be covered by `Scan` - first, the types of assemblies for `AutoMapper` and `MediatR` were not included in `AssemblyMarkerTypes`, and the second reason (basically why they were not included) - library developers added those methods so library consumers do not need to bother with what and how needs to be registered for them to function correctly, cause surely there can be stuff which requires different lifetimes and/or is registered as types (i.e. something like `services.AddX<SomeConcreteType>()`).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that ...

```
this.AssemblyMarkerTypes
```

... refers to an Enumerable of types from each assembly holding services to be registered.  This is passed to Scrutor's [Scan](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/blob/master/src/Scrutor/ServiceCollectionExtensions.Scanning.cs) extension method to perform the registrations.

It is likely that the Enumerable of types only marks assemblies that under the source control of the owner of the solution you are working on.

AddMediatR and AddAutoMapper are extension methods provided by the respective packages to register and configure all services required for their operation (that are not going to be in the list of assemblies marked by AssemblyMarkerTypes).  This is why these calls are still required.